# Access and chart through perl arrays

Tags: javascript, perl, highcharts

I am trying to write code this way in `perl`.

```
\$('#AmpCovPlot').highcharts({

    var amp_name = new Array[$amp];
    var amp_cov  = new Array[$cov]
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average cov'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [amp_name]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Amp name'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: [amp_name]
        data: [amp_cov]

  }]
});
```

so `$amp` and `$cov` are `perl` variables containing array elements, generated by statement :

```
 my $Cov=join(",",@cov);
```

> And I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier". I know I am doing a blunder, and I am new to javascript.

Can somebody let me know how to fix this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you using perl to create javascript to run in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

"Unexpected Identifier" is a hint for invalid Javascript. In your case, i think you `print` the Javascript Code without double quotes `qq{}`, to be more precise: You `print` a `$` where no `$` is allowed or you dont print a `$` where a `$` is expected.

When you just Copy + Pasted your Javascript code, you have a syntax Error as well:

```
var amp_cov  = new Array[$cov] // no semicolon ;
// what is the following part for? you dont really assign that stuff to
// something .... seems wrong
chart: {
    type: 'line'
},
title: {
    text: 'Average cov'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [amp_name]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Amp name'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: [amp_name]
    data: [amp_cov]

}]
```

The next part is the `join` of the `Perl` Array. You need to quote the Variables inside the Javascript as well:

```
var array = ['a','b','c'];
```

So your `join` need to be something like:

```
my $cov = join q{,}, map {qq{'$_'}} @cov;
```

Which just mean, that you first add single quotes to each element in `@cov` and then `join` all with `,`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining variables inside object, which is not proper for JS:

```
$('#AmpCovPlot').highcharts({

var amp_name = new Array[$amp]; // not here!
var amp_cov  = new Array[$cov]  // not here!
chart: {
    type: 'line'
},
title: {
    text: 'Average cov'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [amp_name]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Amp name'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: [amp_name]
    data: [amp_cov]

}]
});
```

This should be done this way:

```
var amp_name = new Array[$amp]; // here define variables
var amp_cov  = new Array[$cov]; // here define variables

$('#AmpCovPlot').highcharts({ ... }); // and create chart
```

Comment: Alright, Thanks for your answers. I figured out the errors with your help, but it takes away errors but would not get me what I want. So the code so far is:      \$('#AmpCovPlot').highcharts({

         chart: {
             type: 'line'
         },
         title: {
             text: 'AmpName'
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: [$ampID]
         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: 'AmpCov'
             }
         },
         series: [{
             name: [$ampID],
             data: [$ampCov]
           
       }]
     });

 })

Comment: I would like to generate a line chart for each element in one array obj to its value in another array obj. Can any of Highcharts support folks help me?

Comment: Is `amp_name` variable already array? Maybe you don't need second `[]`? Also, make sure returned is tru array, not a string. Unfortunatetly I'm not familiar with perl.

Comment: and I am not familiar with javascript. when I declare amp_name array inside highcharts function, it chokes.When I declare outside it works but no plot.  I guess accessability issue?

Comment: Tell me how your data looks like. Add before creating chart `console.log($amp)` and post here outdpu from JS console.